# Unzip .gz file when line order is important

Tags: linux, unzip

I am trying to unzip fastq.gz files and then analyze the sequencing data within them. However, later analysis is dependent on preservation of line (line 1 from zipped file must be line 1 in unzipped file) in  order within the unzipped files.

When I manually look at the files, it seems to me that line order is being preserved when using gunzip to unzip the fatsq.gz files (and I wouldn't expect anything else). However, downstream analysis fails because order has not been preserved from the original file. Am I missing something about the unzipping process?

It appears that something like the following is happening.

Sequencer writes data to fastq.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
lin4
```

Then zips it into fastq.gz. I then unzip using gunzip and appear to get something like the following, where line order is disrupted:

```
line2
line1
line4
line3
```

Comment: this belongs on [su] or [linux.stackexchange.com]

Comment: @Daniel A. White is right, but can you detail the question here too?\

Comment: Yeah I'll add it there. And hopefully the additional information clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

A `gzip`/`gunzip` cycle *should not* - and we can be reasonably confident that it *does not* - modify the contents of a file. Moreover, data corruption and algorithmic bugs in this case normally show up as a whole bunch of garbage, not as neatly reordered text lines.

A few  alternatives:

- Your sequencer does not actually output those lines properly ordered in the first place.
- If multiple uncompressed files are involved, it may be that your sequencer does the equivalent of `gzip -c file* > fastq.gz`, with the input files being named `file1 file2 ... file9 file10`. When `file*` is expanded in alphabetic order for such files, `file10` will be processed before `file2`, thus messing-up the order in the output.
- If multiple compressed files are involved then the same mistake may be happening when decompressing.